# Is it possible to chain classes and ids in a similar way to CSS using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to chain classes and ids in a similar way to CSS using jQuery?
For example, if I wish to target different browsers I would apply the following to my HTML tag:

```
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->

        <!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->

        <!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html> <![endif]-->

        <!--[if !IE]><!--> <html class="notIE">             <!--<![endif]-->
```

This would allow me to target an element in ie7 specifically using:

```
.ie7 #div{
 float: left
}
```

I wish to follow a pattern of graceful degredation on my website and I know that a certain jQuery plugin I wish to use does not work well in IE7 or IE8 ( it throws the style out of position for example) therefore I wish to prevent the jQuery plugin from triggering in IE7 and IE8. How would I do this?

Comment: have you tried it? Did you read *any* of the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/)?

Comment: This is a question and answer format question aimed at people trying to find the answer to this simple question on here. I noticed it hadn't been answered elsewhere so I thought I'd include it in a sort of basic tutorial format. I don't understand why it's been downvoted, it's a genuine question someone would ask.

Comment: What you have is an answer seeking a question. The question itself is bad, which is why the question has been downvoted. The answer doesn't work well for the poorly phrased question, so it's been downvoted as well. While answering your own question should be encouraged, you need to actually have a question that can reasonably be answered.

Comment: What I have is a question and an answer. Downvoting should be used when the information in a question or answer is vague or incorrect in some way. The information here is correct and may be helpful to noobs learning jQuery. The answer may be obvious to us experienced ptogrammers but it doesn't mean it will be for them.

Comment: As per the downvote hover text (emphasis mine): "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or **not useful**" I would expect anyone asking questions to take the time to research their issue before asking a question. This question can easily be answered by reviewing the jQuery documentation, and therefor is completely useless. Please take some time to review the [faq], and if you have further issues, raise a question on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: You are thinking from the perspective of someone who has been developing for a while. Think of those people who have just started using jQuery. This question and answer is aimed at them. It clearly defines a simple question and provides a simple answer. I suppose you'd be happier if it simply asked: How can I run jQuery functions on html elements in specific browsers only?

Comment: Don't take downvotes personally. Comments are not the place for this discussion. I've already told you to open a question on meta.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in jQuery. In fact it's pretty much the same notation you would see in CSS. For example, let's look at this function below that is designed to rotate an image slightly on hover. I wish to apply this function to an image with the id 'head' (Rotate is a jQuery plugin and not part of the basic library). Let's say we wish to target ie9. We would simple use the notation below:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
$(".ie9 #head").hover(function(){
    $(".ie9 #head").rotate(-10);
    },

    function() {
    $(".ie9 #head").rotate(0);
    }
  );
});
```

Notice how the header id is prefixed by the .ie9 class. This is exactly the same as the methodology you would use in CSS.

Comment: OPs code does have spaces between the selectors

Answer (score 1):

Your selectors should be working, so it would be worth testing them with something simple like

$(".lte9 #head").css('color','red');

If that doesn't work then your selector is wrong.